# Slide up UIView using kCATransitionPush 

Tags: iphone, uiview, core-animation, uiviewanimationtransition, catransition

I am trying to have a UIView slide up a quarter of the page to reveal another view underneath it (to display options), and then slide back down to cover those options.  I've searched SO relentlessly but can't seem to find what I'm looking for. I do not want to use a modalview as I want to maintain the top view on the screen. In the code below, I have it sort-of working, the top level slides up, but then completely disappears (fades) out.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

```
HomeOptionsViewController *homeOptionsViewController  = [[HomeOptionsViewController  alloc] 
                      initWithNibName:@"HomeOptionsViewController" 
                      bundle:nil];
// get the view that's currently showing
UIView *currentView = self.view;
// get the the underlying UIWindow, or the view containing the current view
UIView *theWindow = [currentView superview];

UIView *newView = homeOptionsViewController.view; 
//newView.frame = CGRectMake(0,300, 320,140);
    newView.frame = CGRectMake(0,-10, 320,140);
// remove the current view and replace with myView1
//---[currentView removeFromSuperview];
[theWindow addSubview:newView];

theWindow.frame = CGRectMake(0,-110,320,200);

newView.frame = theWindow.bounds;
// set up an animation for the transition between the views

CATransition *animation = [CATransition animation];
[animation setDuration:0.5];
[animation setType:kCATransitionPush];
[animation setSubtype:kCATransitionFromTop];
[animation setTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut]];
//[theWindow setFrame:CGRectMake(0,200,320,300)];
[[theWindow layer] addAnimation:animation forKey:@"SwitchToView1"];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any reason why you're not using standard `UIView` animations? CATransitions will entirely change the view because its supposed to be a transition from one view to the other.

Have you tried something like this? You add the view you want to slide just off the bottom of the screen, then animate both frames changing. It creates a slide up effect.

```
newView.frame = CGRectMake(0,416,320,140);
[theWindow addSubview:newView];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"SwitchToView1" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
theWindow.frame = CGRectOffset(theWindow.frame, 0, -140);
newView.frame = CGRectOffset(newView.frame, 0, -140);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks Mishie.  No particular reason why I used CATransitions other than to say I didn't know any better. I did try your code to use standard UIViews but it's still not providing the desired effect. theWindow view does slide up, but the newView just appears at the top of the screen, over theWindow view and then slides down. I'd like theWindow view to slide up and newView to appear under, at the bottom. How can I control the animation using standard UIView? Thanks!

Comment: You just need to set the frame coordinates correctly. I'm not sure what the starting frame of your newView was so I just kind of guessed =)